# How does the diffuse uniform is set from color property for THREE.MeshBasicMaterial

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

Can someone explain the process of rendering a MeshBasicMaterial, specifically how does the color property ends up being a uniform and decides the fragment colors.

Usage:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    map: imgTexture,
    color: diffuseColor, // how does this color decide the fragment color?
    reflectivity: beta,
    envMap: alpha < 0.5 ? reflectionCube : null
} );
```

How does three.js use this shader for MeshBasicMaterial?
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshbasic_frag.glsl.js#L30

```
// how does this uniform diffuse set?
uniform vec3 diffuse;
uniform float opacity;
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1954

```
// I suppose this sets the uniform
uniforms.diffuse.value.copy( material.color );
```

This is called [from](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1832)

```
// what is m_uniforms type?
refreshUniformsCommon( m_uniforms, material );


// above definition
// what is materialProperties.shader.uniforms
m_uniforms = materialProperties.shader.uniforms;
```

I should just debug the examples, but a three.js tutorial on inner workings would be nice.

Comment: Well, the uniform upload happens in [WebGLUniforms](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLUniforms.js). This component manages the actual calls of [WebGLRenderingContext.uniform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/uniform). Is that the bit you are looking for?

Comment: If it was me and I wanted to know how it worked I'd make the simplest scene possible and then [step through it in the debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/).